# Enable touch and action listener on uibutton at same time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uitouch

Sorry for my lack of knowledge, i want to know that is this possible that we can enable both action listener and touch (dragging button `UITouch`) at same time. I did this but i can only detect action listener(`IBAction`) my dragging functionality not work on button. Thanks in advance. Happy Day!

Comment: My requirement is this that I need both functionality at same time

Comment: try UIControlEventTouchDragInside or UIControlEventTouchDown along with Touchup Inside

Comment: Thanks Naveen but I need to use button on touchbegan also and at same time with my own touchupinside.I dun want Touchdraggin action or touchdown because these are ibaction but i need uitouch flavor Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uibutton will "eat" all touches, so u cannot use your custom view. u can add multi-action on  one btn:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton .....];    
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(drag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];
```